# Слайдер на js с разным временем прокрутки изображений

Tags: javascript, jquery

столкнулся со сложностью (незнанием своим) в реализации слайдера на js с 2-мя единовременно отображаемыми картинками(общее кол-во 3), которые подгружали бы картинки с некоторой асинхронностью. Слайдер сам по себе я реализовал следующим образом:

```html
    <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider__wrapper">
              <div class="slider__item">
                <div style="height: 250px; background: orange;">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="slider__item">
                <div style="height: 250px; background: green;">2</div>
              </div>
              <div class="slider__item">
                <div style="height: 250px; background: violet;">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="slider__item">
                <div style="height: 250px; background: coral;">4</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="slider__control slider__control_left" href="#" role="button"></a>
            <a class="slider__control slider__control_right slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a>
          </div>
```

```css
  .slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .slider__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  }

  .slider__item {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .slider__control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 50px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }

  .slider__control:hover,
  .slider__control:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    opacity: .9;
  }

  .slider__control_left {
    left: 0;
  }

  .slider__control_right {
    right: 0;
  }

  .slider__control::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }

  .slider__control_left::before {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }

  .slider__control_right::before {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }

  .slider__item>div {
    line-height: 250px;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```js
'use strict';
    var multiItemSlider = (function () {
      return function (selector, config) {
        var
          _mainElement = document.querySelector(selector), 
          _sliderWrapper = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__wrapper'), 
          _sliderItems = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__item'), 
          _sliderControls = _mainElement.querySelectorAll('.slider__control'), 
          _sliderControlLeft = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_left'),
          _sliderControlRight = _mainElement.querySelector('.slider__control_right'),
          _wrapperWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderWrapper).width), 
          _itemWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(_sliderItems[0]).width),
          _positionLeftItem = 0, 
          _transform = 0, 
          _step = _itemWidth / _wrapperWidth * 100, 
          _items = [];

        // наполнение массива _items
        _sliderItems.forEach(function (item, index) {
          _items.push({ item: item, position: index, transform: 0 });
        });

        var position = {
          getItemMin: function () {
            var indexItem = 0;
            _items.forEach(function (item, index) {
              if (item.position < _items[indexItem].position) {
                indexItem = index;
              }
            });
            return indexItem;
          },
          getItemMax: function () {
            var indexItem = 0;
            _items.forEach(function (item, index) {
              if (item.position > _items[indexItem].position) {
                indexItem = index;
              }
            });
            return indexItem;
          },
          getMin: function () {
            return _items[position.getItemMin()].position;
          },
          getMax: function () {
            return _items[position.getItemMax()].position;
          }
        }

        var _transformItem = function (direction) {
          var nextItem;
          if (direction === 'right') {
            _positionLeftItem++;
            if ((_positionLeftItem + _wrapperWidth / _itemWidth - 1) > position.getMax()) {
              nextItem = position.getItemMin();
              _items[nextItem].position = position.getMax() + 1;
              _items[nextItem].transform += _items.length * 100;
              _items[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _items[nextItem].transform + '%)';
            }
            _transform -= _step;
          }
          if (direction === 'left') {
            _positionLeftItem--;
            if (_positionLeftItem < position.getMin()) {
              nextItem = position.getItemMax();
              _items[nextItem].position = position.getMin() - 1;
              _items[nextItem].transform -= _items.length * 100;
              _items[nextItem].item.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _items[nextItem].transform + '%)';
            }
            _transform += _step;
          }
          _sliderWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(' + _transform + '%)';
        }

        var _controlClick = function (e) {
          var direction = this.classList.contains('slider__control_right') ? 'right' : 'left';
          e.preventDefault();
          _transformItem(direction);
        };

        var _setUpListeners = function () {
          _sliderControls.forEach(function (item) {
            item.addEventListener('click', _controlClick);
          });
        }

        _setUpListeners();

        return {
          right: function () { 
            _transformItem('right');
          },
          left: function () { 
            _transformItem('left');
          }
        }

      }
    }());

    var slider = multiItemSlider('.slider')
```

не знаю как сделать так, что бы скажем правая картинка уезжала влево с одной скоростью, а новая выезжала с другой.  SOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал по другому - прицепил 2 функции с разными интервалами прокрутки к кнопкам(стрелкам). использовал GSAP. Немного костыль но зато работает.

Comment: Простите, но по правилам so это не является ответом. Вот если бы вы описали как именно -- тогда да, можно было бы считать ответом. Рекомендую дополнить ответ подробностями.

Comment: а еще лучше оформлять "фрагментом кода", чтобы люди не тратили свое время